# Raspberry Pi python code running from Thonny IDE but does not run from the terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading

I am trying to run three python codes from a single python code. However, the code does not run from the terminal. However, when I try to run it using Thonny IDE all the codes run perfectly. Below is the code that I am trying to execute:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
import threading
import os


def startProgram(i):
    if i==0 or i=='0':
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system("sudo python3 /home/pi/a.py")
        print("Create tunnel code executed")
    elif i==1 or i=='1':
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system("sudo python3 /home/pi/b.py")
        print("Create capture http code executed")
    elif i==2 or i=='2':
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system("sudo python3 /home/pi/c.py")
        print("Create mail transaction details code executed")
    else:
        print("Value not in range")
        pass

def main():
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
        t = threading.Thread(target = startProgram, daemon=True, args=(i,))
        t.start()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

No error is thrown in the terminal. The code just runs and exits but the other 3 programs never get executed. I am trying to execute the python code in the terminal with the following command:

> python3 startProgram.py

Also, I have tested all the codes individually and they run without any errors. Please let me know where am I going wrong and how to fix the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing the "sudo" from each os.system call.

Comment: Tried by removing "sudo". Still doesn't execute from the terminal.

Comment: If your main threads ends and only daemonic threads are left the program will shut down ungracefully. You should join the threads at the end of `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other scripts are all .py's why not just import them?

Assuming startProgram.py is in the same folder as your other files --

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

import a, b, c


def startProgram(i):
    try:
        sleep(1)
        [a.main(), b.main(), c.main()][int(i)]
    except:
        print("Value not in range")

def main():
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
        Thread(target = startProgram, daemon=True, args=(i,)).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```